# How do I splat the arguments to the `or` function?

Tags: conditionals, mapping, iteration, boolean

I would like to evaluate a list of booleans like

```el
(nil nil t)
```

into a single boolean, such that if any element is true, then the expression evaluates to true.

I first looked at the `(or)` function in elisp, but it does not take a list of booleans as an argument. Instead it requires its arguments to be "un-wrapped" outside of a list. In other words,

```el
(or (nil nil t))
```

simply evaluates to the entire list `(nil nil t)` because it treats the it as a single argument. I would like something that instead evaluates exactly to `t`. - *I understand that `(nil nil t)` is truthy, but that's beside the point*.

How can I convert `(or (nil nil t))` into just `(or nil nil t)` or just `t`?

After some thought, I can think of

```el
(eval (cons 'or '(nil nil t)))
```

but is there some other more idiomatic way that I'm missing?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted this for a *function* you would use `apply`, but as `or` is a special form you can't do that.  In particular, `or` only evaluates as many arguments as it needs to.

You could write a macro:

```el
(defmacro or-list (list)
  `(or ,@(eval list)))

(setq mylist '(a b c))
```

`(or-list mylist)` then expands to `(or a b c)`

Comment: To help future searches, it should help to note that this answer makes use of backquotes and splicing, as described in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
(defun or-list (list)
  (cl-some #'identity list))
```

Here `cl-some` takes two arguments: a predicate and a list and returns non-nil if the predicate applied to some member of the list is non-nil.  In our case, the `identity` function is a good predicate since we only want to test whether our list members are themselves non-nil.

Comment: Good. But it might help to elaborate a bit, explaining how the code does what's requested.

Comment: @Drew: done!  (Though I think the code is pretty self-explanatory.)